# ERROR when using getDate() in oracle to update rows

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-update

I have a table with a column called STREAM_TIME of DATE type.
I'm trying to update all rows for that column to today's date. The database used is oracle.

My query:

```
update bns_bess_messages SET stream_time=getDate();
```

Oracle comes back with this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "GETDATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

**How can I update STREAM_TIME to today's date?**

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
update bns_bess_messages set stream_time = trunc(sysdate);
```

Or if you want to get the exact time:

```
update bns_bess_messages set stream_time = sysdate;
```

To check you can use the following query:

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

Comment: thanks; it worked :) I was told to use getDate(), it seems I was misinformed

Comment: `getDate()` is a T-SQL function.

Answer (score 5):

getDate() is part of sql server function for oracle use one of below

make use of

```
select current_date
from dual;

update bns_bess_messages SET stream_time=current_date
```

or

The built-in function SYSDATE returns a DATE value containing the current date and time on your system. For example,

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Dy DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "Current Time"
from dual;

update bns_bess_messages SET stream_time=sysdate
```

Answer (score 5):

Oracle uses `sysdate` instead of `getDate()`

```
update bns_bess_messages SET stream_time=sysdate;
```

Comment: ya it seems I was misinformed. tx